# Creating a custom field type

Tags: entities, 8

I'm trying to create a custom FieldType which provides the fields for a complete address (street, house_number, post_code and city).

I created a `FieldWidget`, `FieldFormatter`, and a `FieldType` class and a field template, following [Drupal 8: Creating a custom field - Part 1: Field type](http://www.computerminds.co.uk/drupal-code/drupal-8-creating-custom-field-part-1-field-type).

The widget is not rendered, unless I add a `hook_element_info()` implementation and a `hook_preprocess_address()` where I have to define the same stuff defined in `FieldWidget::formElement()`.

This is the Drupal 7 way, though. Am I missing something?

#### FieldWidget class

```php
public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $element = $element + array(
    'street' => array(
      '#title' => $this->t('Street'),
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]->street) ? $items[$delta]->street : NULL,
      '#required' => FALSE,
    ),
    'street_nr' => array( /* … */),
    'zip' => array( /* … */),
    'city' => array( /* … */),
  );

  $form['#validate'][] = array($this, 'validateCompleteAddress');

  return $element;
}
```

#### FieldFormater class

```php
public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items) {
  $elements = array();

  $elements['addresses'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#tree' => true,
  );

  foreach ($items as $delta => $item) {
    $elements['addresses'][$delta] = array(
      '#theme' => 'fields_address',
      'elements' => $item,
      // 'street' => String::checkPlain($item->street),
      // 'street_nr' => String::checkPlain($item->street_nr),
      // 'zip' => String::checkPlain($item->zip),
      // 'city' => String::checkPlain($item->city),
    );
  }
```

#### FieldType class

```php
public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
  $properties = array(
    'street' => DataDefinition::create('string')->setLabel(t('Street'))->addConstraint('Length', array('max' => 255)),
    'street_nr' => DataDefinition::create('string')->setLabel(t('Street number'))->addConstraint('Length', array('max' => 100)),
    'zip' => DataDefinition::create('string')->setLabel(t('Zip'))->addConstraint('Length', array('max' => 5)),
    'city' => DataDefinition::create('string')->setLabel(t('City'))->addConstraint('Length', array('max' => 255)),
  );
    
  return $properties;
}
      
public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition) {
  return array(
    'columns' => array(
      'street' => array(/* … */),
      'street_nr' => array(/* … */),
      'zip' => array(/* … */),
      'city' => array(/* … */),
     ),
     'indexes' => array(),
     'foreign keys' => array(),
   );
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code you wrote, for which you want to write better code, or you want to understand why it doesn't work, but you didn't show the code you are using, or the part of the code that is relevant for the question. [See Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: added some code of the classes

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you are asking. There is *nothing* special about what viewElements() returns and what you can do anywhere else with render arrays. If you use theme functions or special #type's, then you need to define them yourself. There is no magic.

Comment: It was not clear to me, that one has to define the same stuff **twice**. (backend and frontend)

Comment: Seems like one has to provide a custom "Element" class in module\Element folder to define custom Input elements for the form rendering:

      @see \Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Textfield

Answer (score -1):

It seems like I have to provide a custom `Element` class in the module\Element folder to define the custom input elements for the form rendering.

See [`\Drupal\Core\Render\Element\Textfield`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!Element!Textfield.php/class/Textfield/8).